# Redux persist does not change my desired data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I am trying to using Redux-Persist with ReactJs. I want to save a token to local storage using redux persist. I have only one reducer which I used to create the persisted reducer. I want to be able to access the token using `this.props.token` in the child component which I connected using connect. However, `this.props.token` gives me an object like so `{_persist: {…}}`.

Here are my relevant configurations

reducer,

`const tokenReducer = (state=null, action) => action.payload;`

actions,

```
// use when a token is received after logging in
export const setToken = (token) => {
    return {
        type: 'NEW',
        payload: token
    }
}

// use if login has failed
export const clearToken = () => {
    return {
        type: 'EMPTY',
        payload: null
    }
}
```

store and persistor,

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, tokenReducer);

const myStore = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const myPersistor = persistStore(myStore);
```

component where the store and persistor are passed,

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={myStore}>
                <PersistGate loading={<p>loading...</p>} persistor={myPersistor}>
                    <div>
                        <HomePage />
                    </div>
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

HomePage component needs to obtain or change the token,

```
// the component that it is connected to
// wil have token as a prop
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    token: state
});

// the component that it is connected to
// will have setNewToken and clearToken as props
// object structure {a, b} equivalent to {a: a, b: b}
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
    setToken,
    clearToken
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(HomePage);
```

Am I doing something wrong? I need to persistently store the token and retrieve it somehow. Also, if I exclude the redux-persist and only use redux for temporary storage, then it works as intended and I get the token. Only when I include the redux-persist variables does `this.props.token` give me the `{_persist: {…}}` object. Yes, I need to use class-based components for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I found out that the state will always be a Javascript object in the following:
`const tokenReducer = (state=null, action) => action.payload;`

So I needed to change the reducer as follows:

```
// if there is a token, return it
// otherwise return null
const tokenReducer = (state=null, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'NEW':
            return {
                token: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return {
                token: null
            };
    }
};
```

In mapStateToProps, I was erroneously assign the entire state object to token every time it was triggered as follows:

```
// the component that it is connected to
// wil have token as a prop
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    token: state
});
```

I should have assigned the token attribute of the state object like so:

```
// the component that it is connected to
// will have token as a prop
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    token: state.token
});
```

Explanation:

In HomePage, I can now call `this.props.token` to get the currently stored token. In order to change or delete token, I can call `this.props.setToken(tokenValue)` and `this.props.clearToken` respectively.

In the case of `setToken(tokenValue)`, it will return `'NEW'` as `type` and `tokenReducer` will return an object with `action.payload` as the value of the `token` attribute whose value will be the `tokenValue` that I passed when I called `this.props.setToken(tokenValue)`. As for `clearToken`, it will return `'EMPTY'` as `type` and so tokenReducer will return an object with `token` set to `null`.